# How to add data from android studio into realtime database firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After the registration, I could login using those created emails and passwords but I noticed that there was no single data in real time database [Firebase] . I tried to use email as primary key but it seems like nothing happened after pressing 'Save button'. I tried to look on youtube vides to solve this problem but it's still not working.

Code on Register.java.

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mFullName,mEmail,mPassword,mPhone;
    Button mRegisterButton;
    TextView mLoginButton;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    users users;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mFullName           = findViewById(R.id.Name);
        mEmail              = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword           = findViewById(R.id.Password);
        mPhone              = findViewById(R.id.Phonenumber);
        mRegisterButton     = findViewById(R.id.registerbutton);
        mLoginButton        = findViewById(R.id.loginpage);
        users               = new users();

        reference=rootNode.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

        }


        mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();


                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
                {
                    mEmail.setError("Email is required!");
                    return;
                }

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
                {
                    mPassword.setError("Password is required!");
                    return;
                }

                if(password.length() < 6)
                {
                    mPassword.setError(("Password must be longer than 6"));
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"User Created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Error" + task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This data is self made ,not from the database or after registered.
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/meet2602/SignUp-Sign-In-System   that is example

Comment: https://github.com/meet2602/SignUp-Sign-In-System/blob/029cc00dc8104a18a5042379b9ee209ca93bd26a/app/src/main/java/com/signupsigninsystem/RegisterActivity.java#L193-L230

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo No data in real database when clicked on register button

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo if(task.isSuccesful) works fine to me so far, I haven't test the 'else' part.

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  No data in real database when clicked on register button

Comment: i don't immediately see code that writes to the database in what you shared. Are you sure this is a [minimal, complete/standalone reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem?